# create a polars dataframe containing unique values from a set of CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, duckdb, python-polars

I have +3000 CSVs with +10 columns. What I need is to get all unique values from just two of these. I am able to read unique values in polars:

```
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.read_csv("test1.biobank.tsv.gz", sep='\t', dtype={"#chrom": pl.Utf8}, n_threads=8, columns=["#chrom", "pos"], new_columns=["chr", "pos"]).drop_duplicates()
```

I can read the remaining files one by one, i.e.:

```
df2 = pl.read_csv("test2.biobank.tsv.gz", sep='\t', dtype={"#chrom": pl.Utf8}, n_threads=8, columns=["#chrom", "pos"], new_columns=["chr", "pos"]).drop_duplicates()
```

check if all the values are not equal:

```
if not df1.frame_equal(df2):
    df = df1.vstack(df2)
    del(df1)
    del(df2)
```

then `.drop_duplicates()`. But since all the input files are already sorted on the two columns (chr, pos) and the differences are in thousands out of 16M input rows I hope there is a better way to do it.

Thank you for your help in advance

DK

**edit**

There is another way to do it using Polars and DuckDB.

- create parquet files for each of the inputs

```
tsv_pattern = "gwas_*.gz"

for fn in glob.glob(tsv_pattern):
    print(fn)
    parquet_fn = fn.replace(".gz", ".chr_pos.parquet")
    df = pl.read_csv(fn, sep='\t', dtype={"#chrom": pl.Utf8}, n_threads=8, columns=["#chrom", "pos"], new_columns=["chr", "pos"]).drop_duplicates()
    df.to_parquet(parquet_fn, compression='zstd')
    del(df)
```

- run duckdb and execute:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 'my_directory/*.parquet'
```

Credits go to Mark Mytherin from DuckDB

Comment: Why you want something else then `drop_duplicates` is it running too slow? Semantically its the same as what you do with duckdb.

Comment: Polars is super fast for drop_duplicates (15s for 16M rows and outputting zstd compressed parquet per file). I was looking for a way to do it in 3k files, preferably in polars.

Comment: You can read all files to a `DataFrame` into a list and then use `pl.concat(list_of_dfs).drop_duplicates()`. So we `pl.concat` we concattenate all `DataFrame` into a single table and then finally we drop all duplicates.

Comment: I will try to do that, but I am bit worry about putting 3K data frames with 16M rows. If frame_equal() is super fast I may compare each new frame to already created ones. Or do this in batches. What would you suggest?

Comment: What is your worry? Memory capacity? You could create reduce size by calling `drop_duplicates` after each csv is parsed and then one final `drop_duplicates`, similar to what you do in duckdb.

Otherwise it doesn't really matter. If all the data would be in a single csv, the compute would be approximately the same. The concats are cheap (if you don't rechunk).

Comment: Yes, RAM may be an issue IMHO. To be on the safe side I wrote parquet Partitioned Datasets using Polars & Arrow, computed md5 on all .parquets and run at the moment DuckDB on the unique parquets from a given partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob patterns to read the csv's and then call `distinct`.

```py
(pl.scan_csv("**/*.csv")
 .unique()
 .collect())
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like merge k sorted arrays,
i've found a article for the solution, wish it could help：
https://medium.com/outco/how-to-merge-k-sorted-arrays-c35d87aa298e